# MySQL query optimization access method.

Tags: mysql

What does it mean to have access type "All" in the query optimizer? I found this using the explain=format json statement in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

"ALL" means it's a full table scan, no index can be used at all, this is not good, you'd better add some indexes.

Check out the [Mannul](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html#explain_type)

Answer (score 0):

Here "ALL" means your query's return output after a full table scan is done for each combination of rows from the previous tables. This is normally not good if the table is the first table not marked const, and usually very bad in all other cases. Normally, you can avoid ALL by adding indexes that enable row retrieval from the table based on constant values or column values from earlier tables.

One problem here is that MySQL can use indexes on columns more efficiently if they are declared as the same type and size. In this context, **VARCHAR** and **CHAR** are considered the same if they are declared as the same size. **Table1.column1** is declared as **CHAR(10)** and **Table2.column2** is **CHAR(15)**, so there is a **length mismatch**. if both table's **both columns** have **same datatype and length** that give more **optimize output**.

Mostly developer make many indexes on one table, so you can specify which index use for your query by **use keyword "USER INDEX"**
e.g:

```
SELECT select_fields
FROM tablename USE INDEX(indexname)
WHERE condition;
```